# react-responsive-carousel is not displaying images/ not working

Tags: reactjs, react-responsive-carousel

```
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";

function App() {
  return (
    <Carousel showArrows={true}>
      <div>
        <img src="../assets/1.jpeg" alt="image1" />
        <p className="legend">Legend 1</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="../assets/2.jpeg" alt="image2" />
        <p className="legend">Legend 2</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="../assets/3.jpeg" alt="image3" />
        <p className="legend">Legend 3</p>
      </div>
    </Carousel>
  );
}

export default App;
```

i added the css file in App component similar like [react-responsive-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel) but it is not working

```
carousel.min.css
```

```
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
```

It should be working but not sure why this is happening

Comment: By not working what do you mean? Like the image not showing up, or the carousel is not sliding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about this library, But I can see you are not doing something complicated with your carousel. So basically why don't you create one for yourself?
I have a base code that could help you in this matter.
I create a carousel with React and Static UI(HTML, CSS, JS).
I think it can actually help you out.

[replit](https://replit.com/@farbodesham/packageless-modal-carousel?v=1), [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/packageless-modal-carousel-gg92q3), [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/packageless-modal-carousel?file=src/App.js&hideDevTools=1)

these versions are written with html css js and nothing else.

[replit](https://replit.com/@farbodesham/packageless-modal-carousel-html-css-js?v=1), [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/packageless-modal-carousel-html-css-js-yl7z0s), [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/packageless-modal-carousel-html-css-js?file=index.html&hideDevTools=1)

In your scenario I will do this:

```js
const modalSlidesContainer = document.querySelector(".modal-slides-container");
const modalWidth = 300;

let modalPage = 0;



const nextPage = () => {
  modalPage++;
  modalSlidesContainer.style.margin = `0px 0px 0px -${modalWidth * modalPage}px`;
};

const previousPage = () => {
  modalPage--;
  modalSlidesContainer.style.margin = `0px 0px 0px -${modalWidth * modalPage}px`;
};
```

```css
/* you set root to define varibales */
:root { 
  --modal-width: 300px;
  --modal-height: 400px;
  --number-of-pages: 5;
}


html body{
  margin: 0px;
}

.modal-background{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw; 
  height: 100vh; 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
  z-index: 0;
}


.modal-boundary{
  width: var(--modal-width); /* the width boundary must be as same as every modal slide*/
  height: var(--modal-height);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
  /* the max width must be as same as the width of modal ModalBoundary*/
  @media screen and (max-width: var(--modal-width)) {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
}

/*  This container contains every slide you gonna use in your modal   */
.modal-slides-container{
  min-width: calc(var(--modal-width) * var(--number-of-pages)); /* The width must be total width of all the slide you gonna use */
  height: var(--modal-height);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: white !important;
  /*here is how to control carousel movement*/
  margin: 0px; /*this how we control the place of the modal*/
  transition: margin 1s; /*this how you control the animation of carousel when it's changing steps */
  }

  
.modal-slide{
  width: var(--modal-width);
  height: var(--modal-height); /* in this scenario the total height of slide must be as same as modal height*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white !important;
 }

.button-container{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.navigation-button{
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="modal-background">
    <div class="modal-boundary">
      <div class="modal-slides-container">
        <div class="modal-slide">
          <img alt="first image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
          <p> Legend One </p>
          <div class="button-container">
            <button onclick="nextPage()" class="navigation-button">
              next
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-slide">
          <img alt="second image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
          <p> Legend Two </p>
          <div class="button-container">
            <button onclick="previousPage()" class="navigation-button">
              previous
            </button>
            <button onclick="nextPage()" class="navigation-button">
              next
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-slide">
          <img alt="third image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
          <p> Legend Three </p>
          <div class="button-container">
            <button onclick="previousPage()" class="navigation-button">
              previous
            </button>
            <button onclick="nextPage()" class="navigation-button">
              next
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-slide">
          <img alt="fourth image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
          <p> Legend Four </p>
          <div class="button-container">
            <button onclick="previousPage()" class="navigation-button">
              previous
            </button>
            <button onclick="nextPage()" class="navigation-button">
              next
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-slide">
          <img alt="fifth image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
          <p> Legend five </p>
          <div class="button-container">
            <button onclick="previousPage()" class="navigation-button">
              previous
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I hope this helps you.^-^

Comment: i forgot to add that the library is in the project where i'm working, and it's very simple for implementation, something like [this](https://react-responsive-carousel.js.org/) i was testing in my local system but the issue is the images are itself not working

Comment: In react you first need to import your image as variable and then pass them to img tag like this: `import randomImage from "../assetes/randomImage.png`
then use it like this: `<img alt="something" src={randomImage} />`

Comment: Can't believe how i missed this. It's working now

Comment: I am glad to hear that^-^.  @njz